# Why would a cygwin program lose path prefix when running under gdb?

Tags: debugging, file-io, gdb, filesystems, cygwin

I just came to a really strange problem with gdb with a relatively large software build in Cygwin64 on Windows 10, which I cannot really reproduce with a minimal example.

So, let me first provide a minimal example that works fine (and does not reproduce the error): basically, the below code (`test_cygwin.cpp`) just wants to create [exclusive access file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388212/what-is-the-written-out-word-for-o-excl) in `/var/run`.

Let's recall that `/var/run` is a Unix path, and as such does not exist in Windows; otherwise it is mapped to the Windows filesystem through a directory in the Cygwin installation:

```
$ cygpath -w /var/run
C:\cygwin64\var\run
```

Here is `test_cygwin.cpp`:

```cpp
// compile with:
// g++ test_cygwin.cpp -g -o test_cygwin.exe

#include <iostream> // cout
#include <errno.h> // errno
#include <string.h> // strerror
#include <fcntl.h> // open
#include <unistd.h> // close

int main(void) {
  std::string filepath("/var/run/test");
  std::cout << "opts: " << O_RDWR << " | " << O_CREAT << " | " << O_EXCL << " , " << S_IRUSR << " | " << S_IWUSR << " | " << S_IRGRP << " | " << S_IWGRP << " | " << S_IROTH << " | " << S_IWOTH << std::endl;
  int my_fd = open(filepath.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);
  if (my_fd < 0) {
    std::cout << "Failed to open " << filepath << ": " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  std::cout << "Opened " << filepath << std::endl;
  close(my_fd);
  return 0;
}
```

So, basically, if I run this program and the file does not exist, the file is created; if the file exists, the program reports an error - in Cygwin's bash shell:

```
user@DESKTOP-COMPUTER /tmp
$ ls -la /var/run/test
ls: cannot access '/var/run/test': No such file or directory

user@DESKTOP-COMPUTER /tmp
$ ./test_cygwin.exe
opts: 2 | 512 | 2048 , 256 | 128 | 32 | 16 | 4 | 2
Opened /var/run/test

user@DESKTOP-COMPUTER /tmp
$ ls -la /var/run/test
-rw-r--r-- 1 user None 0 Oct  8 14:38 /var/run/test

user@DESKTOP-COMPUTER /tmp
$ ./test_cygwin.exe
opts: 2 | 512 | 2048 , 256 | 128 | 32 | 16 | 4 | 2
Failed to open /var/run/test: File exists

user@DESKTOP-COMPUTER /tmp
$ rm /var/run/test && ls -la /var/run/test
ls: cannot access '/var/run/test': No such file or directory
```

Ok, so far so good. Now, the `opts` are printed out, so that I could re-run the open command from within a `gdb` session; again in Cygwin bash:

```
$ gdb --args ./test_cygwin.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 10.2-1) 10.2
...
Reading symbols from ./test_cygwin.exe...
(gdb) b test_cygwin.cpp:13
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1004011f2: file test_cygwin.cpp, line 13.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/test_cygwin.exe
[New Thread 12044.0x467c]
[New Thread 12044.0x4f8]
[New Thread 12044.0x280]
[New Thread 12044.0x9b4]
opts: 2 | 512 | 2048 , 256 | 128 | 32 | 16 | 4 | 2

Thread 1 "test_cygwin" hit Breakpoint 1, main () at test_cygwin.cpp:13
13        int my_fd = open(filepath.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);

(gdb) p (int)open("/var/run/test", 2 | 512 | 2048 , 256 | 128 | 32 | 16 | 4 | 2)
[New Thread 12044.0x42a0]
[New Thread 12044.0x2ff8]
$1 = 3

(gdb) p (int)open("/var/run/test", 2 | 512 | 2048 , 256 | 128 | 32 | 16 | 4 | 2)
$2 = -1

(gdb) c
Continuing.
Failed to open /var/run/test: File exists
[Thread 12044.0x1c14 exited with code 1]
[Thread 12044.0x9b4 exited with code 1]
[Thread 12044.0x280 exited with code 1]
[Thread 12044.0x4f8 exited with code 1]
[Thread 12044.0x42a0 exited with code 1]
[Thread 12044.0x2ff8 exited with code 1]

Program terminated with signal SIGHUP, Hangup.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb) quit
```

So, in the above snippet, the breakpoint halts the program right before it attempts to open the file, and the file is created manually by running `p (int)open("/var/run/test", 2 | 512 | 2048 , 256 | 128 | 32 | 16 | 4 | 2)` in the `gdb` shell.

The first invocation of this command in the `gdb` shell succeeds (3 is returned, as the numeric file descriptor of the newly opened file); the second fails (-1 is returned) - and when the program proceeds, it clearly fails, as the requested file exists already.

So far, so good - all is as expected.

---

Now, here is the problem I have in my actual build - which I cannot reproduce here:

- When I run the program normally (e.g. `./myprogram.exe --arg1=1 ...`), the `open` call succeeds
- When I run the program via `gdb` (that is, `gdb --args ./myprogram.exe --arg1=1 ...`), the `open` call *always fails*, with "No such file or directory"

So, similar to the above, I placed a breakpoint right before that open command in the actual program, and I've tried (making sure I've deleted `rm /var/run/test` at start):

```
(gdb) p (int)open("/var/run/test", 2 | 512 | 2048 , 256 | 128 | 32 | 16 | 4 | 2)
$27 = -1
(gdb) p (int)open("/var/run/test", 2 | 512 | 2048 , 256 | 128 | 32 | 16 | 4 | 2)
$28 = -1
```

Yup, so it fails already at very start; however, if I now add the cygdrive prefix:

```
(gdb) p (int)open("/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/var/run/test", 2 | 512 | 2048 , 256 | 128 | 32 | 16 | 4 | 2)
$29 = 26
(gdb) p (int)open("/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/var/run/test", 2 | 512 | 2048 , 256 | 128 | 32 | 16 | 4 | 2)
$30 = -1
```

... then it succeeds, from within `gdb`?!?! And indeed, the Cygwin `bash` shell also sees this file afterwards:

```
$ ls -la /var/run/test
-rw-r--r-- 1 user None 0 Oct  8 14:50 /var/run/test
```

Recalling the error message from the first example: if I want to create a file (`/var/run/test`) with `open`, and I get "No such file or directory" error - I interpret that as the parent directory (here `/var/run`) not existing, at least from the perspective of the program.

So, in *this particular case*, when `gdb` debugs this particular `myprogram.exe`, it has somehow "lost" the reference to root Unix paths (I've confirmed that also creating a file in `/tmp` fails in this case); or in other words, the program in `gdb` cannot see these paths (and so these paths don't exist for this program) - however, it can still access the same folder locations, and successfully open/create a file, by having the Cygwin installation path prefixed.

The strange thing being, that `/cygdrive` is *also* a Unix path formulation, albeit specific to Cygwin?! Also, interestingly, even when debugging this program, I can "see" these directories from `gdb` itself:

```
(gdb) cd /var/run
Working directory /var/run.
(gdb) pwd
Working directory /var/run.
```

... so, `gdb` in itself still "sees" these directories - even if the debuggee program does not?!

So, my question is: while the minimal example clearly shows that this is not a general issue with `gdb` in Cygwin - has anyone ever experienced, that a Cygwin program "loses reference" to (or "cannot see") Unix system paths when running in `gdb`; but otherwise sees these paths fine when running directly from the Cygwin `bash` shell?

If so, would anyone have an explanation why does this situation occur - and how to rectify it (that is, make the `open` succeed, also when the program runs under `gdb` - just as well as when the program runs standalone in the Cygwin `bash` shell)?

(just as a clarification note on why I want to know this: the actual program I'm debugging segfaults after the `open` call, which I'd like to catch in `gdb`; however, since the `open` call fails in `gdb`, the program under `gdb` currently cannot even get to the point that otherwise segfaults).

Comment: I got around this, as I was lucky that in my actual program, the call to open happens way before, the program waits for an interactive input; so I just ran the program, waited until it comes to the "waiting for interactive input" state, and then used `gdb attach` to attach to the process, and debug further. However, it would still be great to know, what are the specific circumstances leading to this behavior ...

Comment: I notice that the permissions on `/var/run/text` is not what you requested. You asked for `0666` (`rw-rw-rw-`) but got `0644` (`rw-r--r--`). This suggests that the Windows permissions on `/var/run` are interfering with your expected permissions.